# Path to the CSS file in the header generated by IntelliJ is incorrect

Tags: css, node.js, intellij-idea, express-handlebars

I'm running a node.js project on localhost that I created with IntelliJ idea, and overall, it seems to work fine on Chrome from a usability standpoint. However, the CSS files don't resolve so I'm not getting any styles. Using the developer tools on Chrome, I can see that it can't find them. But it sure seems like they are there to me.

However, the main problem that I see is that headers are being added to the handlebars files which contain one of the broken shortcuts. Anyone know where in IntelliJ this is coming from? I tried adding the header info but it just is creating duplicate information.

The first set of info is the one that isn't coming directly from the file I created. I'm just not sure where it's coming from.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your file structure?

Comment: I put the file everywhere, but I think I eventually figured it out - the problem is in the Express code setup that I had. The express defined a "static" file location for the public directory, so the trick to is to start the path with "/Static", like this <link rel='stylesheet' href='Static/stylesheets/style.css' /> Then it finds it any I'm good to go!

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out - the problem is in the Express code setup that I had. The express setup defined a "static" file location for the public directory, so the trick to is to start the path with "/Static", like this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='Static/stylesheets/style.css' />
```

Then it finds it and I'm good to go!